# Infinite redirect loop - rewriting URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo, infinite-loop

I am getting an infinite redirect loop when implementing a rewrite of URLS for SEO purposes.

Example url

```
`<a><?php echo make_store_name_url($store_id); ?><?php echo $store_name; ?></a>`
```

I have a function to rewrite dynamic urls - the below is an example

```
function make_store_name_url($store_id)

{
     //build the keyword rich url
     $url = SITE_URL . '/store/' . $store_id .'/';

    //return the URL
    return $url;
}

//function to redirect using 301
function fix_store_name_url()
{
   $proper_url = get_proper_store_name_url();

   if(SITE_URL . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != $proper_url)
   {
      header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
      header('Location: ' . $proper_url);
      exit();
   }
}

function get_proper_store_name_url()
{
  $store_id = $_GET["store"];  
  $proper_url = make_store_name_url($store_id);
  return $proper_url;
}
```

Finally my line in htaccess to rewrite. Note that the rewrite works fine when no        redirection is used.

```
RewriteRule ^store/([0-9]+)/$ /store_selection.php?store=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Not sure what is going wrong with my infinite redirection loop. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: After the `$proper_url = get_proper_store_name_url();` insert this line and see whether the 2 URLs are actually similar. 
`echo SITE_URL . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . ' = ' . $proper_url; exit;`

Comment: I did the above and they are similar so I am assuming there is an issue with my rewrite. @blackpla9ue

Comment: If you don't mind can you paste the output printed from the code that I gave?

Comment: http://localhost/Testing/versions/version_three/Testing/versions/version_three/store/8/ = http://localhost/Testing/versions/version_three/store/8

Comment: I note from pasting it I am getting double of the URL

Comment: and the last `/` is missing too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your .htaccess to:

```
RewriteRule ^store/([0-9]+)/$ /store_selection.php?store=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This just internally rewrites the URL while the user is still shown the original. You had set it to do a 301 Redirect so the URL the user was hitting is /store_selection.php?store=id viz the reason for the infinite loop.

Comment: I still get a redirection loop. I have checked the headers using fiddler and the location being the rewritten url is correct however I still get 21 301 redirects. @Birla

Comment: @user2058618 It works perfectly for me. However, if I change `QSA` back to `R=301` it gets stuck in a infinite loop. There might be a caching issue in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Why not debug the rewrite rules with RewriteLog?

```
# Roll your own Rewrite log
# Log details via scale of 1 to 9
# 1 = few details, 5 = enough details, 9 = too much detail
RewriteEngine On
RewriteLog "/your/path/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 5
```

http://perishablepress.com/roll-your-own-apache-rewrite-log/